# How to access to array in JSON ANGULAR?

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to show an array in the view of my Angular project

Items.json

```
{
  "tipo": "texto",
  "texto": "Un colegio necesita enviar 5 estudiantes como representantes a un foro sobre la contaminación del medio ambiente. Se decidió que 2 estudiantes sean de grado décimo y 3 de grado undécimo. En décimo hay 5 estudiantes preparados para el foro y en undécimo hay 4. ¿Cuántos grupos diferentes pueden formarse para enviar al foro?",
  "respuestas": [
    "9",
    "14",
    "20",
    "40"
  ]
}
```

TS:

```
let timeoutMS = 10000;
this.http.get(assets / Items.json)
    .timeout(timeoutMS)
    .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        let responseData = data;

        this.preguntas = responseData;
        console.log(this.preguntas);

    },
    err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

[console.log() displays the JSON correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WW0Y.png) respuestas is an Array, so it is OK

[In the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGmbY.png)
 I get `preguntas.texto = "Un colegio necesita enviar 5 estudiantes..."` and `preguntas.respuestas = 9,14,20,40` .

If I try to get preguntas.respuestas[0] I have this error "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] ... "

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for reading! :D

EDIT:

```
import { Facebook, FacebookLoginResponse } from '@ionic-native/facebook';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';

import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-pregunta',
  templateUrl: 'pregunta.html'
})
export class PreguntaPage {
    userData = null;
    preguntas = {};
constructor(private facebook:Facebook ,  public http: Http) {
  }

ionViewDidLoad() {
    let path = 'assets/Items.json';
    let encodedPath = encodeURI(path);
    let timeoutMS = 10000;

    this.http.get(encodedPath)
    .timeout(timeoutMS)
    .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
let responseData = data;

this.preguntas = responseData;
    console.log(this.preguntas);
},
err => {
  console.log('error!!', err);
});
}}
```

Comment: Yes, I am very confused because `preguntas.texto` is working

/ Same error :(

Comment: http is **asynchronous**. So, between the moment your view is displayed, and the moment your http response comes back, preguntas is equal to the value you initialize it with. Presumably an empty object, otherwise preguntas.texto would also cause the same exception.If you posted all the releant code, it would be much easier to help. And post it as text, not as a link to an image.

Comment: Often times if you just need to wait until your http call is made before the view is rendered (resulting in an error), you can just wrap the displayed element in a div with an `*ngIf="preguntas && preguntas.respuestas && preguntas.respuestas[0]"` and it will be displayed once that property exists.

Comment: I guess using a safe operator i:e elvis operator in Angular might help like preguntas?.respuestas[0] can you try this ?

Comment: preguntas.texto is working and preguntas.respuestas too

preguntas.respuestas[n] isn't

Comment: Rahul, same error using `preguntas?.respuestas[0] `

Comment: I have created a function in my controller:

`log(){
  console.log(this.preguntas['respuestas'][0]);
}`


and it is not undefined

The error is in the view (There is no problem when I use *ngfor )

Comment: @JeanRodríguezcan you have plunker for the same ?

Comment: @RahulSingh I don't think so, Angular + Ionic 3

Comment: can we have a team viewer ?

Comment: I just replicated the issue it works fine for me @JeanRodríguez

Comment: @RahulSingh can you show me your code, please?

I don't have a good connection here, sorry

Comment: its the same actually that i showed in the comment i am using the star wars api  http://swapi.co/api/planets/1/ and i am getting the residents array value using the same i showed you

Comment: *preguntas.texto is working and preguntas.respuestas too preguntas.respuestas[n] isn't*: that's expected. For an unknwon reason, you hav initialized preguntas to an empty object (instead of leaving it undefined). So, before the response is available, you can display `preguntas`: it's an empty object; you can display `preguntas.texto`: it's undefined, since preguntas is an empty object; you can display `preguntas.respuestas`: it's undefined since preguntas is an empty object;

Comment: but you **can't** display `preguntas.respuestas[n]`, because it would need to access the nth element of `preguntas.respuestas`, but that's impossible since `preguntas.respuestas` is undefined. Just leave preguntas as undefined, and only display its content once it isn't undefined anymore.

Comment: Thank you so much @RahulSingh, using the 'Star Wars api' I checked the correct way 

(I tried this before but I didn't get success)

`{{preguntas?.respuestas[3]}}`  

Could be due to the browser cache I use for debugging

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You should to try something like this:

```
let respuestas = []
...
responseData.respuestas.map(item => respuestas.push(item)).
```

and then try something like this:

```
console.log(respuestas[0])
```